# Is it secured to accept and execute user provided CURL commands

Tags: design, java, architecture, security, linux

Assume you have to figure out a dynamic way where the user can provide an API call to hit in the backend
for example, user to provide a webhook to call on his end server

So, An idea for users to provide a CURL command in UI would be an ideal way to cover all cases such as request method types, authorization, params... etc

Then this CURL command gets sent to the backend and gets saved in the database for future use

Then when the time to use it, it gets executed with the native OS command from the Java code

This solution offers a very dynamic way of building a request giving the user all flexibility possible

But since the curl command is going to be executed from the backend against the server OS, User can simply provide some malicious script into that CURL command which can cause serious damage to the server

is there a way to either validate the CURL command or execute the command at a higher level than the OS

Comment: Relevant [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a lot of things that can go wrong here, security-wise.

- Insufficient shell escaping could lead to arbitrary code execution on your server.
- Vulnerabilities in curl could lead to arbitrary code execution on your server.
- Niche features of curl could lead to arbitrary code execution on your server.
- Network requests could be used to attack your server infrastructure from within.
- Network requests from your servers could be used to attack, DDoS, or harrass third parties.

There are also lots of ways how you can make this safer:

- You can parse the provided curl command to ensure that it only uses features you're comfortable with. If any unexpected option is used, deny the command.
- You can execute the curl program directly without needing shell escaping, e.g. using `Runtime.exec(String[])` rather than the less-safe `Runtime.exec(String)`.
- You can use containerization technology to execute the command in a sandboxed environment.
- You can resolve the domain name of the URLs to ensure that the command will only contact servers outside of your network.
- You can rate-limit requests.
- You can provide this functionality only for verified, paying customers.
- You can implement observability and anomaly-detection features to try to detect abuse.

Personally, I would find it too difficult to make curl safe. Yes, it offers a lot of features, but that breadth of features also implies a huge attack surface for you to defend. Instead, I would let users define only certain options that I'm fairly sure are safe, such as URL and authorization token headers. Webhook-style functionality typically doesn't need a lot of features.

Comment: ... and these are only the security risks on the OPs server - not to forget about the risks introduced for the foreign server involved in this scenario.

Comment: Using [libcurl](https://curl.se/libcurl/) rather than `curl` itself would sidestep some of these issues (in particular shell escaping). But the general sentiment is absolutely correct.